# How to get the GitHub username in Github OAuth Next.js sign-in callback for adding to a database?

Tags: typescript, github, oauth, next.js, jwt

> **1. Summarize the problem**

I am currently building a Full Stack Website using Next.js and Typescript, and I am stuck on persisting the Github Username to store in the database when the user will sign in via Github OAuth.

Should I be storing something else like the ID? However, I want my website to be able to "domain.com/[github username]"?

I am trying to use the Github username as the primary key for storing the userdata in the database (mongodb).

I add the user id currently to the database during the sign-in callback in [...nextauth].ts.

Here is my [...nextauth].ts

```
/*
File: [..nextauth].ts
Description: This file will uses nextAuth to handle the requests, res of any OAuth...
*/
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github"
import type {CredentialsProvider} from "next-auth/providers";
import axios from "axios"
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb";
import {useSession} from "next-auth/react";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret : process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
            
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
        // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
        if(profile){
            token.login = profile.login
            // @ts-ignore
            user.login = profile.login
            console.log(user)
            // code up here is the user name in the jwt but user.login isn't being persisted in session nor signin
            token.id = profile.id
        }
        if (account) {
            token.accessToken = account.access_token
        }
        return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user}) {
            // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            session.login = token.login;
            session.id = token.id;
            // @ts-ignore
            console.log(user.name)
            return session
        },
        async signIn({ user: User, account:Account, profile: profile, email:Email }) {
            // define client
            const client = await clientPromise;

            // define database
            const db = client.db("userData");

            // define users
            const users = db.collection("users");

            console.log(User.login)


            try{
                // get user data
                const insertDocument = {"_id":User.id, "User":User}
                // @ts-ignore
                const dataUsers = await db.collection("users").insertOne(insertDocument);
                if(dataUsers){
                    console.log("Added " + String(User.id) + " to database!")
                    return true;
                }

                // if we are here user simply could not be added at all...

                return false;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("User could not be added to database due to an error or either existing")
                return true;

            }
            return true;
        },
    },
    debug:true,
});
```

However, the real problem is I cannot seem to find the "login/username" in side of the sign in call back with the given arguments of the function.

```
       async signIn({ user: User, account:Account, profile: profile, email:Email }) {
```

> **2. Describe what I've tried**

I have found that the Github username is here in the JWT function. However, I declare the variable accordingly and User does not have that property any where else.

```
async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
        // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
        if(profile){
            token.login = profile.login
            // @ts-ignore
            user.login = profile.login // code here is the user name in the jwt but user.login isn't being saved in the other functions for Arg User
            persisted in session nor signin
            token.id = profile.id
        }
        if (account) {
            token.accessToken = account.access_token
        }
        return token
        },
```

> **3. Code deep-dive**

At this point, I am only able to get the userid which is a number that maybe Github uses also to store their data. But, I **need** the Github username.

```
try{
                // get user data
                const insertDocument = {"_id":User.id, "User":User}
                // @ts-ignore
                const dataUsers = await db.collection("users").insertOne(insertDocument);
                if(dataUsers){
                    console.log("Added " + String(User.id) + " to database!")
                    return true;
                }

                // if we are here user simply could not be added at all...

                return false;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("User could not be added to database due to an error or either existing")
                return true;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for the exact same and achieved it by [overriding the default `profile` callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#using-a-custom-provider) of the GitHub OAuth provider to return additional [profile properties](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/providers/github.ts).

I went with this solution which also returns the login:

```
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      profile(profile: GithubProfile) {
        return {
          id: profile.id.toString(),
          name: profile.name,
          userName: profile.login,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.avatar_url,
        };
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2024 answer for the Firebase with React Web modular API

You can print out the current user object you get from `auth.onAuthStateChanged` like this:

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


  // place into component that initiates login with signInWithRedirect or signInWithPopup

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Listen to auth state changes
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged", "User is signed in:", user);
      } else {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged", "User is signed out");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

The `currentUser` within firebase `auth` will contain the required github username + internal github user id:

```js
const auth = getAuth();
console.log(auth.currentUser.reloadUserInfo.screenName);
console.log(auth.currentUser.reloadUserInfo.providerUserInfo[0].rawId);
console.log(auth.currentUser.reloadUserInfo.providerUserInfo[0].screenName);
```

If you look into the [firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#user_interface), the screen name is not documented there. So I think this might be an internal property that may be changed any time.